# passing Python variable to triple quoted curl command

Tags: python-2.7

```
SIZ=100

imap_cmd="""
curl -s -X GET --insecure -u xxx https://xxxxx/_search?pretty=true -d '{
"from":0,
"size":%SIZ,
"query":{ "match_all": {} },
"_source":["userEmail"]
}' | grep -i userEmail|awk {'print $3'} | cut -d ',' -f1
"""
def run_cmd(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    output = (p.communicate()[0])

    return output
```

I'm trying to pass the SIZ (python) variable to the curl command, but it is not interpreting the value when i execute the command. what I'm missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the `%` formatter in this line,

```
"size":%SIZ,
```

try

```
imap_cmd="""
curl -s -X GET --insecure -u xxx https://xxxxx/_search?pretty=true -d '{
"from":0,
"size":%d,
"query":{ "match_all": {} },
"_source":["userEmail"]
}' | grep -i userEmail|awk {'print $3'} | cut -d ',' -f1
""" % SIZ
```

[Here](https://pyformat.info/) is more info on formatting strings.